# Many authentication in Kafka server visible when using callback handler and authenticate over external system

Tags: authentication, session, apache-kafka, callback, spring-kafka

We are using Kafka callback.handler [KIP-86](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-86%3A+Configurable+SASL+callback+handlers) to delegate the authentication to an external system (Keycloak).
`listener.name.sasl_plaintext.plain.sasl.server.callback.handler.class=com.xxxxxx`

Our java spring kafka producer client is configured with default parameters : such max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=5

We released a multiple authentication request coming to our Keycloak.
My question is : How a kafka client handle a session ( is it TCP session or other ? ), and why we have such connection request every seconds ( less than one minute )

Thank you !

We tried to debug the client and Kafka server

Answer (score 0):

The authentication occurrences are cause by an idle activity.
`connections.max.idle.ms` was equals 9 minutes. The network Selector `o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector` close the connection after 9 min of inactivity and org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient try to create a new one.
Increasing `connections.max.idle.ms` can resolve the multiple authentication request to Kafka.